# How to add an app to to list of default apps programmatically?

Tags: c#, uwp

Windows has settings for default apps, see image below.

I want to add my app to be in the list of photo viewer apps.

I have added image file types jpg and png to the file type associations in `Package.appxmanifest`. The app shows in the list of apps when I right click an image and go to "Open with >", but it doesn't show in the list of default apps in the settings.

How can I add my app to be in the list of apps on the default apps settings page programmatically? I would like to do this in the code of my UWP app.

Note: I don't want to set my app to be a default app, I only want it to show up as an option on the "Choose an app" dialog.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I could reproduce your problem, and in general, if you have added image file types jpg and png to the file type associations in `Package.appxmanifest`, your app will display in the default app list. I will confirm this with team if there are some new update in the latest version.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I only added .jpg and .png, I added .jpeg as well, not the app shows up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `package.appxmanifest` file only had .jpg and .png as known file type.

After adding .jpeg as well, the app shows up in the list of default image viewer apps.

```
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType ContentType="image/jpg">.jpg</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType ContentType="image/png">.png</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType ContentType="image/jpg">.jpeg</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
```